# Nuances between words meaning "official" and "formal"

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Specifically, I am thinking of 形式, 公式, 公, and 正式. I have a vague notion that 公式 is closer to the English "official" in that it is for typically for some explicitly declared things by an organization like a 公式発表 or a 公式見解, but beyond that the nuance eludes me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that looking at the kanji and example sentences should probably give you a hint about the meaning.

`正式` the correct/proper form

```
彼女は夫と正式に離婚した
```

She divorced from her husband in the correct form (legally/officialy).

彼女のその服は正式なパーティーでは場違いだ

Those clothes of her, in a party in the correct form (formal) are out of place.

`形式` seems more associated with format.

```
彼はそれを小説の形式で表した
```

He expressed it in the form of novel.

But also formality

```
一般に若者は形式を嫌う
```

In general, young people dislike formalities.

```
形式的な文体で書きなさい
```

Write using a formal literary style.

This could easily be written using 正式.

`公式` is the form that is for the public. I think you get this one. It's really close to the "official" word in english, But it can also be used as "formula" in the mathematical sense.

`公` seems to lean to the "public" meaning in the sense that it's not private.

```
その老人は１０年前に公の生活から引退した。
```

The old man retired from public life ten years ago.

I hope this helps somehow.